# Get user uid from Facebook with Django Social Auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I'm trying to get the user profile picture from Facebook with django-social-auth.

I saw in an other post, that I should get the user uid from Facebook to have access to the profile picture.
How can I get the uid?

From django-social-auth I just installed it and configured the basic stuff to login/logout with django-registrations.

This is my html to login:
Login with FB

How can I do a request to a 'home' view to the user in facebook and get the uid?

I found this in the django-socail-auth docs:

```
def social_associate_and_load_data(backend, details, response, uid, user,
                                   social_user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    The combination of associate_user and load_extra_data functions
    of django-social-auth. The reason for combining these two pipeline
    functions is decreasing the number of database visits.
    """
    extra_data = backend.extra_data(user, uid, response, details)
    created = False
    if not social_user and user:
        social_user, created = UserSocialAuth.objects.get_or_create(
            user_id=user.id,
            provider=backend.name,
            uid=uid,
            defaults={'extra_data': extra_data})

    if not created and extra_data and social_user.extra_data != extra_data:
        social_user.extra_data.update(extra_data)
        social_user.save()
    return {'social_user': social_user}
```

Where should I put it in my django app? In views.py? If it yes, how can I activated the view, if I'm just logging in with commom social-auth urls.

Comment: Facebook `uid` is stored in `UserSocialAuth` instance, you can get it by doing `user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').uid`.

Comment: Thanks! Never noticed it

Comment: BTW, django-social-auth library has been deprecated. Please check their documentation for more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook `uid` is stored in `UserSocialAuth` instance, you can get it by doing

```
user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').uid
```